# How do you stub an SMTP error for ActionMailer::DeliveryJob

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer

What is the proper way to stub an SMTP error to test your `discard_on` or `retry_on` for your `ActionMailer::DeliveryJob` methods?

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't find any examples, but this is the best I could come up with:

```
  test 'capture an SMTP exception' do
    email = MyMailer.with(params).my_message
    Mail::Message.any_instance.stubs(:deliver).raises(Net::SMTPSyntaxError)
    job = email.deliver_later
    job.perform_now
    assert_equal 1, job.executions
  end
```